# Some concerns about unanswered questions

Tags: discussion

There are still 29% unanswered questions right now.

Based on my observation, there are numbers of questions which have good answers, but as there are no upvotes on these answers or the author don't accept these answers(maybe they never come to DS SE again?), these questions are classified as "unanswered".

I'm wondering if we can try to sanitizing these questions by upvoting these **good** answers? I don't know if it's allowed in SE, but I think good answers deserve upvotes, and increasing answered rate is just a bonus.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can upvote good answers. Please do, I do the same.
I don't know if there is any mechanism to auto-accept answers though.
I would not worry much about this metric. It's not obvious that it's 'low' even if there's this arbitrary target of 90%. Just help answer, close, vote.

Answer (score 3):

You're absolutely right. A year back, this site was having a very low Questions and daily users count. [Most people thought it'd be dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266067/difference-between-the-cross-validated-and-data-science-se-sites#comment863357_266067).

But surprisingly, everything played well, and here we are, almost ready for graduating :)

So yeah, there are questions from those days which have not been upvoted or which haven't received enough attention. So, by all means it's a great idea to share and upvote them.

Also, let's also help answering as many posts as we can, from the [unanswered tab](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/unanswered), to help boost our answered % stat :)

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering if we can try to sanitizing these questions by upvoting these good answers? I don't know if it's allowed in SE, but I think good answers deserve upvotes, and increasing answered rate is just a bonus.

That's exactly what you should do. Unless the answer is of low quality or technically incorrect, you should up-vote the answer.

Once any answer of a question reaches the score of +1 or higher, the question will not be counted against the *unanswered* statistics anymore. The accept-vote is not always required.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that the percentage of unanswered questions is increased by the presence of questions that are duplicates of questions posted on crossvalidated. E.g.,  [How does LSTM fights vanishing gradient?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/17428/843)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170315210218/https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/how-does-lstm-fights-vanishing-gradient)) has 0 answer, partly due to the fact that the same question was asked on crossvalidated and potential answerers didn't feel like copypasting or paraphrasing.

More generally, the large overlap between datascience and crossvalidated may discourage some people from contributing, as it is unpleasant to see wasted community effort.